# Sorting a list of names and dates according to birthday

Tags: python, list, sorting, date, datetime

I have a text file in this format:

```
Robert, 03/07/1960
Michael, 24/11/1942
Simon, 14/08/1924
Sarah, 20/07/1935
Adam, 12/09/1944
Rachael, 24/09/1919
```

So is has name and birthday separated by a comma with a new line for each person.
Using IDLE I want to print the text file and have it listed by birth date oldest to youngest.

I have modified this code used originally for sorting names and scores that I read on stackoverflow. However, having a date instead of a score has presented problems. I have have been reading about the datetime module and have been trying to sort based on the birthday element but I can't seem to make it work.

```
import datetime
format = '%d/%m/%Y'

dates = []
with open("namedate.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line.strip()
        name, date = line.split(',')
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, format)
        dates.append((name, date))

dates.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])

for name, date in dates:
    print(name, date)
```

I receive this error:

```
ValueError: time data ' 03/07/1960\n' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

So I need to cut the '\n' out of the birthday element but can't make it work.

Comment: `line = line.strip()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is:

```
import datetime
format = '%d/%m/%Y'

dates = []
with open("namedate.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        name, date = line.split(',')
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.strip(), format)
        dates.append((name, date))

dates.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])

for name, date in dates:
    print(name, date.strftime(format))
```

And the output will be:

```
('Rachael', '24/09/1919')
('Simon', '14/08/1924')
('Sarah', '20/07/1935')
('Michael', '24/11/1942')
('Adam', '12/09/1944')
('Robert', '03/07/1960')
```

Comment: Thank you arulmr, this is the desired displayed format for the birthdays I was after. That was my next question.